# Tell if $S = (X, \Sigma)$ is a distributive complemented lattice

Tags: lattice-orders

Let $\Sigma$ be a partial order defined over $\mathbb N^* = \mathbb N \setminus \{0\}$ such that $$n\;\Sigma\;m \Leftrightarrow n=m \text{ or } \text{r}(8,n) \text { is a non-trivial divisor of } \text{r}(8,m)$$

where $\text{r}(x,y)$ is the reminder resulting from the division of $x$ by $y$. Consider the following set $T$ and draw the Hasse diagram, explain why it is a lattice, tell if it is a complemented lattice and deduce $(X, \Sigma)$ isn't a distributive lattice.

$$T = \{1,3,5,6,7,9\}$$

I can demonstrate $S = (X, \Sigma)$ to be a lattice by showing that $\forall (a,b)\in X,\; \sup\{a,b\} \in S$ and $\inf\{a,b\} \in S$.

[image]

And I would say it is not complemented because $\sup\{6,5\} = 9 \neq 1$ and $\nexists a \in X : \sup\{6,a\} = 1$. How from that can I deduce it is not distributive? In addition have I correctly calculated that $\sup\{6,5\} = \sup\{3,6\} = \sup\{3,5\} = 9$?

Comment: I am not sure your diagram is correct. If you map $T$ by $x \mapsto r(8,x)$ then you get a multiset $\{0,2,3,2,1,8\}$, that is $\sup\{6,5\} = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two prototypical non-distributive lattices are the diamond and the pentagon (see e.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice)). To prove that some lattice is not distributive you need to check the distributive law for the middle three elements (i.e. $L -\{\top,\bot\}$) of the diamond or the pentagon sublattice.

I hope this helps ;-)